# How can I use Sikuli4Net or SikuliSharp with Visual Studio for Mac to test .NET Core cross platform applications on MacOS?

Tags: macos, .net-core, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, sikuli

I have a cross-platform desktop application written in Xamarin.Forms that runs both in Windows and MacOS. I want to do some UI automation on top of that application.

After some research it seems like the most cross-platform friendly option is to use Something like Sikuli. As the default stack on our team is centered on the .NET stack we want to use SikuliSharp or Sikuli4Net to perform the automated UI tests.

However, despite of the fact that we've been able to run Sikuli4Net successfully on Windows, automating several flows so far. We have a dire situation on MacOS. Our team (myself included) doesn't have a lot (or maybe any) knowledge of Java applications.

I've installed the JDK 8, but was unable to run the tests in the same way we did on Windows. The code builds, but it seems like something in the environment is lacking.

With Sikuli4Sharp when starting the APILauncher like this:

```
launch = new APILauncher(true);
launch.Start();
```

I get the following error:

[image]

With SikuliSharp when trying to run a simple demo application on our software I have this error:

[image]

I have tried to set up the SIKULI_HOME environment variable using this answer as a reference, but still the same problem (and I did restart the console and IDE, even my machine).

When I run `echo $SIKULI_HOME`  on the terminal I do get the directory that cointains the .jar files:

[image]

So I'm kind of lost about were to go from here. These problems made me unsure about being possible to run Sikuli4Net or SikuliSharp on MacOS environments. Is this the case? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the error message: sikuli-script.jar is missing.

You have to check on what version of Sikuli/SikuliX your SikuliSharp or Sikuli4Net are depending on.

In doubt you have to dive into the sources of those Net packages.